# Compression of Dynamic Content in IIS does not seem to be Working

Tags: iis, iis-7.5

I've followed the instructions to implement compression of dynamic content in IIS set out in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17331627/540156).

When I send a request, I cannot see any evidence of the response being gzipped:

[image]

Version of IIS is 7.5

Is there anything obvious I should be checking to troubleshoot this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to tell without seeing any settings or the request, but you should probably double-check that you have the correct mime types set up for the file and that your request is sending the correct accept-encoding header. It should resemble:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
```

Comment: I definitely used that accept header and have added a screenshot of the configuration to the question.