# WebAPI JSON responses not being compressed by IIS

Tags: c#, iis, asp.net-web-api, https

For some reason IIS doesn't seem to want to use gzip to compress the responses of my WebAPI. In the configuration editor of IIS, I've got both **static** and **dynamic** compression enabled as well as **'application/json'** and **'application/json; charset=utf-8'** enabled as Mimetypes. They are also enabled in the config files.

Other settings that may be of note include noCompressionForProxies being set to false, staticCompressionIgnoreHitFrequency being set to true, disableCpuUsage being set to 90 and EnableCpuUsage being set to 50. I've also tested variations on these settings.

My front end requests do have the correct `accept-encoding` headers, but the response headers do not have the correct `Content-Encoding: gzip` headers. The response packet is of adequate size to be compressed (12.2 KB).

There is, however, a header indicating chunked transfer-encoding.

Versioning is as follows: IIS 10.0, .NET 4.5.

Does anyone know what the issue might be here? I've checked all of the other threads and microsoft docs, but none of the solutions seem to be working and many of them seem outdated.

Comment: You need to set IIS compression module to let it know that json should be compressed. Please refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17321131/compression-filter-for-web-api/17331627#17331627) to add json in compression list.

Comment: @BruceZhang - Thank you for the advice, but I'm afraid as stated above that I've already tried that with no luck.