# Compressed Delete Web API throwing exception

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I implemented compression per the solution here:

[Compress HTTP GET Response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443588/mvc4-webapi-compress-get-method-response)

However, my Delete Web API is throwing an exception:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Delete(int id)
    {
        if (_repo == null)
        {
            _uow = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<TPS.Data.Can.IUnitOfWork>();
            _repo = _uow.TradeSpendRepository;
        }
        if (!_repo.Delete(id))
        {
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        _uow.Save();
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    }
```

The exception is thrown in the CompressedContent's constructor because content is null:

```
if (content == null)
{
   throw new ArgumentNullException("content");
}
```

I guess returning a status code isn't enough! What's the best approach to prevent this exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since there is no content here, there is no need of creating a `CompressedContent` here, so you should add an additional check in the message handler.

Example:

```
if (response.Content != null && response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding != null)
{
    string encodingType = response.RequestMessage.Headers.AcceptEncoding.First().Value;

    response.Content = new CompressedContent(response.Content, encodingType);
}
```