# Compress Web API response

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, http-compression

I'm changing my MVC4 Api project to Web Api 2. I had the following filter to compress the response:

```
public class CompressResponseAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
    {
        HttpRequestBase request = filterContext.HttpContext.Request;

        string acceptEncoding = request.Headers["Accept-Encoding"];

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(acceptEncoding))
        {
            acceptEncoding = acceptEncoding.ToUpperInvariant();

            HttpResponseBase response = filterContext.HttpContext.Response;

            if (acceptEncoding.Contains("GZIP"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "gzip");
                response.Filter = new GZipStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
            else if (acceptEncoding.Contains("DEFLATE"))
            {
                response.AppendHeader("Content-encoding", "deflate");
                response.Filter = new DeflateStream(response.Filter, CompressionMode.Compress);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However, the above code doesn't work with Web Api 2. Are there any working examples to handle compression in code (not IIS)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10443588/mvc4-webapi-compress-get-method-response